# Using php to capture certain characters

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, post

I get through a POST form the following numbers: 1,2,3 | 3,4,5 but I just wanted to pick the numbers that are before | and insert into a mysql table one by one, how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$split = explode('|', $string);
$before_pipe = trim($split[0]);
```

Comment: Simple and quick! +1.

Comment: and how to run it all in one array to insert in mysql?

Comment: @GabrielHenrique: `+1` refers to upvote. It requires 125 reputation points, so you can't, yet upvote. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up for details.

Comment: @GabrielHenrique Sorry, I don't understand the question. Do you mean `$_POST['fieldname']` is an array because you have multiple rows in the form? Write a `foreach` loop that runs the above code and then does a database insert.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '1,2,3 | 3,4,5';
$data = trim(strtok($string, '|'));
```

Once you've properly escaped the `$data`, you can `INSERT` them into your database, like so:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ($data)";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

Comment: and how to run it all in one array to insert in mysql?